# How do I find $\;\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{x^2+1} dx\;$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

I'm new here so please, try to bear my poor formatting skills. Here's the problem :

> $I_{n}$ is considered a sequence where $n\in N^*$
>
> $$
> I_{n} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{x^2+1} dx\ , (\forall)n\in N^*
> $$
>
> a) Calculate $I_{2}$
>
> b) Prove that $I_{n+2} + I_{n} = \frac{1}{n+1},(\forall)n\in N^*$
>
> c) Calculate $\lim_{n \to +\infty} nI_{n}$

I have done both a) and b), but I don't exactly know how to solve c).

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: You could perhaps integrate by parts by using $n x^{n-1} = (x^n)'$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\color{blue}{I_{n+2} + I_n = \frac 1{n+1}}$$

Let first define $\color{blue}{I_{(n\to\infty)} = I}$

Here, I believe that there shouldn't be any difference for a value $I_n$ and $I_{n+2}$ as $n\to\infty$ they **must be same** because $n$ is already a very very big number then any small increment like(2) shouldn't make difference provided $n$ is very big number.
$$\begin{align*}
I_{n+2} + I_n
& = \frac 1{n+1}\\
&\lim_{n\to\infty}nI_{n+2} + \lim_{n\to\infty}nI_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+1}\\
& \text{Now, By intuition we can imagine this that when $n\to\infty$ then $I_{n+2} = I_n$ = I}\\
&\text{(As, from above blue color } I_{(n\to\infty)} = I)\\
&2\times\lim_{n\to\infty}nI = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+1} = 1\\
& \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}nI = \frac 12
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the answer ! This does seem like the solution so thank you very much ! I have one more question : What if n is of form 2k+1 ? Will substracting 2 still bring me to bring me to $I_{2}$ ?

Comment: @Doppler Glad to help you! May I know if you could prove $I_{n+2} + I_n = \frac 1{n+1}$?

Comment: Yes ! We add the 2 integrals and get integral of x^n from 0 to 1 which is exactly 1/(n+1) .

Answer (score 10):

We know $x^n \geq x^{n+2}$ in the range $[0,1]$, so that
$I_n \geq I_{n+2}$, implying
$$I_n \geq \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{n+1}.$$
Similarly
$$I_n \leq \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{n-1}.$$
The resulting upper and lower bounds for $n I_n$
each approach 1/2.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and +1 for the very succinct approach

Comment: Welcome to MSE & Very Nice! $\to +1 $ for an astoundingly elegant solution.